# PHP Multidimensional Array Value Replacement

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, foreach

I have been working on a project recently for fun.

It retrieves JSON from a game server, decodes it into an array, and then saves the array values into a SQLite DB (for display / manipulation later). I am new to programming in general, and have never touched PHP prior to this.

My question: Is there a better, more efficient way to handle this?

Basically, this section of code, loops through the large multidimensional array, and replaces values that are equal to a string. It does this prior to insertion into the DB so that I can have fields formatted to be more readable.

The problem is that in the actual script I have a huge list of defined variables now, and like 3 `foreach` loops with a combined 15 or so `if`/`else if`/`else` statements.

```
$sr = "Summoners Rift";
$rs = "Ranked Solo";
$rt = "Ranked Team";
$nr = "Normal";

foreach ($history['games'] as &$typeMode)
{
    if ($typeMode['subType'] == 'RANKED_SOLO_5x5')
    {
        $typeMode['gameMode'] = $sr;
        $typeMode['subType'] = $rs;
    }
    elseif ($typeMode['subType'] == 'RANKED_TEAM_5x5')
    {
        $typeMode['gameMode'] = $sr;
        $typeMode['subType'] = $rt;
    }
    elseif ($typeMode['subType'] == 'NORMAL')
    {
        $typeMode['gameMode'] = $sr;
        $typeMode['subType'] = $nr;
    }
}
```

Comment: You should check out the php switch() function for starters.  More concisely formatted and quicker most of the time.

Comment: Thanks! I cOle2 below also recommended this option with an example. It seems a much better way to accomplish this. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The problem is that in the actual script I have a huge list of defined
>   variables now, and like 3 foreach loops with a combined 15 or so IF /
>   ELSEIF / ELSE statements.

The best solution I can recommend based on the data your are showing is to just create a basic array of structures connected to the data you have and then just use the `foreach` loop to assign values based on that initial array structure:

```
// Set structured array values.
$array_values = array();
$array_values['RANKED_SOLO_5x5']['gameMode'] = "Summoners Rift";
$array_values['RANKED_SOLO_5x5']['subType'] = "Ranked Solo";
$array_values['RANKED_TEAM_5x5']['gameMode'] = "Summoners Rift";
$array_values['RANKED_TEAM_5x5']['subType'] = "Ranked Team";
$array_values['NORMAL']['gameMode'] = "Summoners Rift";
$array_values['NORMAL']['subType'] = "Normal";

// Set structured array values based on the sub type.
foreach ($history['games'] as &$typeMode) {
   $typeMode['gameMode'] = $array_values[$typeMode['subType']]['gameMode'];
   $typeMode['subType'] = $array_values[$typeMode['subType']]['subType'];
}
```

That way `$array_values` always has the preset values in place to begin with. And the assignment just happens via an array key access of `$typeMode['subType']` in the `foreach` loop.

Comment: This is a really interesting solution. I had been approaching this as using the same array from JSON decoding to DB insertion, but perhaps structuring my own array as needed and inserting the appropriate data from the original array would work better.

Answer (score 0):

For things like this I prefer to use the [`switch` control structure](http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php) instead of `if`/`elseif`/`else`, although your approach is perfectly fine, if a little verbose maybe:

```
foreach ($history['games'] as &$typeMode)
{
    $typeMode['gameMode'] = $sr;

    switch($typeMode['subType'])
    {
        case 'RANKED_SOLO_5x5':
            $typeMode['subType'] = $rs;
            break;
        case 'RANKED_TEAM_5x5':
            $typeMode['subType'] = $rt;
            break;
        case 'NORMAL':
            $typeMode['subType'] = $nr;
            break;
    }
}
```

Also if `$typeMode['gameMode']` always equals `$sr;` then you only need that line once.

Comment: Ah! Thank you for the answer. This looks a lot cleaner. I was not aware of 'switch' at all. The $typeMode['gameMode'] can be several other values, I just omitted a large section of the code. I suppose I could do a switch for gameMode outside of the switch for subType then.